# Can I change the default color for Relationship Lines?

Tags: customization

Sorry but I didn't found where to change the default color for relationship lines (for constraints and parents) among Theme settings. Since I really really need to do so in the current project. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but not on their own, this uses the themes wire color which is also used for many other unselected wire-frame data in the view-port. (See: 3D View -> Wire)

Comment: Thanks ideasman42. However, it's only work for parents relations, doesn't work for constraint relations. You know, the dark blue line.

Comment: Regarding the discuss here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/theme-option-for-changing-relation-line-for-constraints 

I bet the answer is: "Z axis" mixed with "Grid". (Quite strange through)