# Theme option for changing relation line for constraints?

Tags: customization, theme

I found the current color for constraint relation line is hard to see a little bit.

I've tried to change the "wire"color in the Theme setting panel, but it seems not work for the relation lines.

[image]

Thanks for your guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the default color for Relationship Lines?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/can-i-change-the-default-color-for-relationship-lines)

Comment: Unfortunately, to me, it seems not working for CONSTRAINTS lines. I don't see anything available for it.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

I see your point. It puzzled me a lot, too.

Currently I found that the only way to change the relationship lines for *constraints* are nothing but the "Grid", not the "Wire".

But, This is really not good for distinguishing the constraint lines from the background, including grid, by doing this. It seems that they are mixed together.

I also hope it may draw dev's attention to improve this. As I said, it's really not good to tweak two different thing by one single option.

Answer (score 1):

## Change constraint line colour

This can be set in the <kbd>File | [User Preference…](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences) | [Themes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Themes)</kbd>. It uses a mix of <kbd>Interface | Axis Colors | Z Axis</kbd> and <kbd>3D View | Theme 3D View | Grid</kbd>.

Comment: Hmm... I think you are half right. As Leon Cheung said, the "Grid" also affect its color partcially. So I bet it is a tweak mixed by Grid and Z Axis? I'm still wondering why it behaves like this...probably kinda bug?

Comment: Right you are, updated to include that.